# AWS EC2 T2 linux instance - get credit balance from inside

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to get the credit balance from inside an instance ?
I guess something like this:

```
 aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUCreditBalance --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistic Maximum  --period 60 --start-time $(date --iso-8601=hours -d "1 hours ago" |sed s/\+.*//)
```

might work but I'd need to supply credentials to all instances.
Also the AWS call is quite heavy on CPU, it would reduce my credit balance and at credit balance 0 it would take quite a while to even execute that command.

Maybe there is another way ?

Mostly I want to detect if the balance is higher or lower than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to supply credentials to all instances. Create an IAM role with just enough privileges to get that metric and attach that role to the instances. In your case, you may want to grant only `get-metric-statistics` to that role.

See: [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

Regarding other ways to get the CPUCredit, there is none as far as I know.

Comment: Not yet successful, I tried creating an IAM policy, give it full read only access to Cloudwatch, started a fresh instance.
But "aws cloudwatch" failed with "aws needs configuration"

I guess I have to download the credentials somehow

Comment: @John you are doing something wrong. You don't need to start a fresh instance, you can attach an IAM profile to a running instance and you don't have to download credentials. What is the error message you are getting when running the AWS CLI?

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know I have to "attach" it somehow, I thought it's automated for all instances.
I just created the policy so far.
The error was: You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/

Comment: aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistic Maximum --period 3600 --start-time 2017-12-03T03:43 --end-time 2017-12-03T07:43 --region us-east-1
{
    "Label": "CPUUtilization",
    "Datapoints": []
}

It's working but always empty, no matter what region or timeframe I try.
I tried exact and very broad settings, never had a single output

Comment: You are missing `--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-12345678`   You can get the current instance id by: `curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/`

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it finally working finally!
They really did not make it easily accessible in comparison to everything in EC2